# Asynchronous SOAP call with Tornado and SUDS

Tags: python, soap, asynchronous, tornado, suds

I am working with Tornado and SUDS. I would like to make an asynchronous call using Tornados AsyncHTTPClient. Here is my code

```
class RequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def post(self):
    data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
    uuid = data['id']
    suds_client = Client(wsdl_location, nosend=True) 
    context = suds_client.service.GetSubscriptions(uuid)        
    tornado_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    tornado_client.fetch(context.envelope,callback=self.on_response)

def on_response(self,response):
    print response
    #self.write(str(response))
    self.finish()
```

I set nosend = True in the above code based on the discussion from the post [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1yf266/tornado_soap_any_nonblocking_soap_libs_out_there/)

It says to set nosend = True and it builds an envelope and then use Tornado asynchronous http agent to fetch it.

When I execute the above code I don't get any response.
How do I do it? Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it myself. I will be providing my code below for reference and understanding.

```
class RequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def post(self):
    data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
    uuid = data['id']
    suds_client = Client(wsdl_location, transport = trans_certs, nosend=True)
    context = suds_client.service.GetSubscriptions(uuid)
    tornado_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    url=context.client.location()
    tornado_client.fetch(url,body=str(context.envelope),method="POST",headers=context.client.headers(),callback=self.on_response)


def on_response(self,response):
    result=str(response.body)
    dom1 = parseString(result)
    for node in dom1.getElementsByTagName('subscriptionId'):
        self.write(str(node.toxml()))
    self.finish()
```

Comment: Hi @navin, I am trying same but not getting any response, can you help to understand what is transport? in your code and what is value of trans_certs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. it worked very well. For making asynchronous SOAP calls in Tornado, we can also use the ThreadPoolExecutor class which executes the blocking method in other threads and not in the ioloop.

```html
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
    import tornado.ioloop
    from tornado import concurrent
    from tornado import gen

    class asyncExec(object):

      def __init__(self,ioloop = None):
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
        self.io_loop = ioloop or tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

      #client is the suds client and remoteMethod is the blocking function

      @run_on_executor
      def getResponse(self,client,args):
        response = client.service.remoteMethod(args)
        return(response)


    #getResponse returns a future object which can be yielded in a coroutine :

  @gen.coroutine
  def makeRequest():
    asyncCaller = AsyncExec()
    response = yield asyncCaller.getResponse(client,args)
    #Do something with response
```